# Android AudioRecord MP3 encoding AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO

Tags: android, performance, audiorecord, lame, jini

I seem to be stuck with this problem,

I am trying to get 
https://github.com/yhirano/SimpleLameLibForAndroid 
to work on channelConfig AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO mode.

Below code works perfectly if i call it with channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO but not with STEREO.

I have played around with

```
 short[] buffer = new short[mSampleRate * (16 / 8) * nChannels * 5]
 byte[] mp3buffer = new byte[(int) (7200 + buffer.length * 2 * 1.25)];
```

bu cannot seem to get it working. I mean it works but recorded sound is like very very slow. Listen to this example https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1465252/1381762795295.mp3

There seems to be another similar question at [Lame encoded mp3 audio slowed down - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084882/lame-encoded-mp3-audio-slowed-down-android) without a solution.

Can anybody help?

Here is the code:

```
  new Mp3Audio(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO, A udioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 128);


 public Mp3Audio(int audioSource, int sampleRate, int channelConfig, int audioFormat, int bitRate) {
    if (sampleRate <= 0) {
        throw new InvalidParameterException(
                "Invalid sample rate specified.");
    }

    mSampleRate = sampleRate;
    mBitRate = bitRate;
    if (channelConfig == AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO) {
        nChannels = 1;
    } else {
        nChannels = 2;
    }
    builder = new Builder(mSampleRate, nChannels, mSampleRate, mBitRate);
    //builder = new Builder(44100, 1, 44100, 128);

    builder.quality(6); 

    mEncoder = builder.create();
    cAmplitude = 0;
    payloadSize = 0;
    aFormat = audioFormat;
    aSource = audioSource;
    mChannelConfig = channelConfig;


}
     public void start() {
 final int minBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(mSampleRate, mChannelConfig, aFormat) * mBufferSizeFactor;      
            if (minBufferSize < 0) {
                AppHelper.Log(tag, "MSG_ERROR_GET_MIN_BUFFERSIZE");
                return;
            }
            AppHelper.Log(tag, "minBufferSize: " +      AppHelper.humanReadableByteCount(minBufferSize, true));
            aRecorder = new AudioRecord(
                    aSource, 
                    mSampleRate,
                    mChannelConfig,
                    aFormat, 
                    minBufferSize);




            short[] buffer = new short[mSampleRate * (16 / 8) * nChannels * 5]; // SampleRate[Hz] * 16bit * Mono * 5sec 
            AppHelper.Log(tag, "buffer: " + AppHelper.humanReadableByteCount(buffer.length, true));
            byte[] mp3buffer = new byte[(int) (7200 + buffer.length * 2 * 1.25)];
            AppHelper.Log(tag, "mp3buffer: " + AppHelper.humanReadableByteCount(mp3buffer.length, true));
```

......
.......

Comment: You need to include the calls you make to the LAME library in your question.

Answer (score 2):

To give you a pointer, you need to invoke lame_encode_buffer_interleaved() if you use 2 channels (.stereo) to record.

It took me a few days to figure it out, this is the code you can use:

```
if (lame_get_num_channels(glf) == 2)
    {
        result = lame_encode_buffer_interleaved(glf, j_buffer_l, samples/2, j_mp3buf, mp3buf_size);
    }
    else
    {
        result = lame_encode_buffer(glf, j_buffer_l, j_buffer_r, samples, j_mp3buf, mp3buf_size);
    }
```